# PHP problems lot of warnings (Exam project, need help!)

Tags: php

I'm getting all these warning:

> E_WARNING Error in file �new.php� at line 214: htmlspecialchars()
>   expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>
> E_WARNING Error in file �new.php� at line 214:
>   mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
>
> E_WARNING Error in file �new.php� at line 216: htmlspecialchars()
>   expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

I'm currently working on my exam and when I had to move my project from XAMPP to my web-server, nothing will work! I have to deliver this project in a few hours, and it's working perfectly on my localhost. But now no matter what I do it wont work.

I'm not a developer. I'm a designer, and I got no clue why this wont work.

This is my code:

```
// connect to the database

include('connect-db.php');



// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($connection, $_POST['submit']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$first = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST ['firstname']));

$mail = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST['mail']));

$adresse = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST['adresse']));

$telefon = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST['telefon']));

$sprog = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST['sprog']));
```

Comment: You should check the manual on the functions you are using...

Comment: Actually the warning message is clear, you are passing an object as first argument of htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($connection, $_POST ['firstname']));
```

Use

```
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST ['firstname']));
```

same is for rest of the variables too. From the error, it is clean clear, [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) should be provided with connection variable, not [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

---

**`mysqli_real_escape_string`** - `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`  [First parameter should be a connection variable and second should be string to be escaped]

**`htmlspecialchars`** - `htmlspecialchars (string $string)` [First parameter should be string to be converted]